# What is included in the syscall.h in Linux?

Tags: aix, system-calls

I am compiling a set of native binaries from source for AIX 7.1. The source code references the `sys/syscall.h` header which is present in Linux but not for AIX. On digging through the raw code, this header is used repeatedly. What is included in this header and is there an alternative?

Comment: The programs you are trying to build are presumably very Linux specific. Tracking down what this header contains will be very low down in the list of your worries. Linux has drifted quite a lot from "standard POSIX" in it's system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man 2 syscall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) says:

```c
#include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_xxx definitions */
```

I checked a couple of usages in other manpages (e.g., [`man 2 clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html#BUGS) or [`man 2 getdents`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html#EXAMPLE)), and `#include <sys/syscall.h>` was indeed followed somewhere down the line by `syscall(SYS_...)`.